# Convert method to return a task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, async-await

How can I turn the below method into the right format for returning a task items. The method stub requires a task to be used. This is my first time into `async` methods I am using it for the windows phone 8 like below:

```
private System.Threading.Tasks.Task listView_PullToRefreshRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Populatelist();
}

public async void Populatelist()
{
        try
        {
            curoListsDal _db = new curoListsDal();
            cLists = await _db.GetListsAync();
            listView.ItemsSource = cLists;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: you can use `async Task MethodName(...)` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right format would be to return a `Task` instead of `void` in `PopulateListAsync` and `await` on that inside your event handler:

```
private async void PullToRefreshRequestAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await PopulateListAsync();
}

public async Task PopulateListAsync()
{
    curoListsDal db = new curoListsDal();
    listView.ItemsSource = await db.GetListsAsync();
}
```

Side note: don't swallow exceptions.